# How many people can legally contest a given mandate at the same time in the United States?

Tags: united-states, vaccination

How many people can legally contest a given mandate at the same time in the United States? A lot of companies intend to legally contest the vaccine mandate that was announced by Biden. I am wondering if judges are allowed to reject some legal contests if too many individuals are contesting it.

#### Sources

- ["State AG Promises Court Challenge of Federal Vaccine Mandate"](https://www.usnews.com/news/best-states/montana/articles/2021-09-10/state-ag-promises-court-challenge-of-federal-vaccine-mandate) from *US News*
- ["A vaccine law expert explains the 3 most likely legal challenges Biden's federal vaccine mandate might face"](https://www.businessinsider.com/vaccine-law-expert-explains-likely-legal-challenges-biden-vaccine-mandate-2021-9) from *Insider*
- ["Current constitutional issues related to vaccine mandates"](https://constitutioncenter.org/blog/current-constitutional-issues-related-to-vaccine-mandates) from *Constitution Daily*
- ["Biden is requiring the vast majority of federal workers to get vaccinated or face disciplinary measures"](https://www.nytimes.com/2021/09/09/us/politics/biden-vaccine-federal-workers.html) from the *NY Times*

Comment: I don't know if there is a limit specified by law; I suspect not. But the normal response to many similar claims is to consolidate them into a single case, or to certify the case as a class action. For challenges to a law as unconstitutional, consolidation is the more usual route. Indeed I am not sure if there can be a  class action against the government in such a case.

Comment: Could you please cite a source, perhaps a published news story, for "A lot of companies intend to legally contest the vaccine mandate that was announced by Biden"

Comment: @Fizz, The US Supreme Ciurt can, and not too infrequently does, overturn its own past fecisi0ons. Presumably any such challenge would seek rto overturn or distinguish *Jacobson v. Massachusetts*. And after all, the mandate upheld in *Jacobson* was a local one, authorized by state law, and the decision stressed **state** power.

Comment: I added some sources, but they do not really show that "many" companies plan to challenge these proposed mandates. Sources that show this would be helpful.

Comment: @David Siegel In a Fox News appearance, [Harmeet Dhillon](https://www.foxnews.com/person/d/harmeet-k-dhillon) has claimed that she has a number of clients seeking to challenge this mandate.  I believe it was on 9/9/21.  I don't know how much credibility to attach to the claim.  I know that Fox News is considered controversial, so I do not want take a side one way or another.

Comment: @grovkin I think it is probable that she said tyhat to Fox. Whether she follows through, who knows?

Comment: Does it really matter whether "many" companies actually plan to challenge the law? This fact pattern is just one to illustrate the broader theoretical question.

Comment: @DavidSiegel whether anyone follows through is questionable.  But she is a lawyer.  She does take on high-profile cases.  So her claim is as good as anyone's.

Comment: @grovkin: Remember that Fox News is not a reliable source.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As many parties as have standing. The First Amendment protects the right to petition for redress of grievances, so any limitation on that right would be highly disfavored.

When there's a rush of cases like this, though, there are a few option for dealing with them. For instance, a plaintiff may seek class certification, permitting him to stand in for similarly situated parties so they don't need to litigate themselves, or a court may consolidate the cases if they are sufficiently similar.